# "Понята", ударение

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

В слове *"понята"* ударение на последний слог? Без вариантов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У этого приставочного глагола на НЯТЬ ударение во всех формах прошедшего времени и причастных формах сдвигается на приставку, кроме форм женского рода:

Пон**я**ть, пон**я**в, пон**я**вший

п**о**нял, п**о**няло, п**о**няли, но: понял**а**

п**о**нятый, п**о**нят,  п**о**нято, п**о**няты, но: понят**а**

Варианты возможны в некоторых случаях, причем они связаны с перемещением ударения на приставку: созд**а**л и с**о**здал, созд**а**ли и с**о**здали.

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла!

Answer (score 3):

Ударение **понятА**, без вариантов.

[Ударение в слове понята | где-ударение.рф](http://xn----8sbhebeda0a3c5a7a.xn--p1ai/%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0/)

Comment: Спасибо, Матвей!